# Rest $http.put gets 403. How to authorize PUT?

Tags: javascript, apache, rest, http, put

I'm using REST, or specifically $http.get and $http.put in my Javascript program, to call a PHP file which reads or writes to a database.  $http.get works but $http.put causes the following error in the browser's console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403
>   (Forbidden)

How do I authorize PUT?

I've tried adding the following to .htaccess :

```
<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>
  Allow from all
</Limit>
```

I had the following in /etc/apache2/mods-available:

```
 <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
 </Limit>
 <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
       Order deny,allow
       Deny from all
 </LimitExcept>
```

I changed it to:

```
 <Limit GET PUT POST OPTIONS>
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
 </Limit>
 <LimitExcept GET PUT POST OPTIONS>
       Order deny,allow
       Deny from all
 </LimitExcept>
```

I reloaded service apache2, but I still get the 403 error.

Comment: A default install of Apache 2 will not throw a 403 for a PUT request. There isn't enough information in your question to determine what is emitting the status code.

Comment: Are you passing the right Authorization headers in your request?

Comment: Quentin What other information should I provide you?

@OluwafemiSule I don't know. How or where do I check the Authorization headers?